# Terraform Range function to start from 1 instead of 0

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to make the range function of terraform start from 1 instead of 0 or any other function or way to achieve the end result.

Let's say I have code as seen below.

```
variable "nodes" {
  default = 1
}

locals {
  node_range = range(var.nodes)
}
```

This returns the following output.

```
[
  0
]
```

I would like to be able to get the output as shown below (pseudo code)

```
[
  1
]
```

The reason I would like to have it this way is that, we cannot use count.index + 1 in for_each resources. Hence, if I get the list from range function which starts from 1, then I can simply use it in other places.

I have name tags that should start from myec2instance01, myec2instance02 ..etc. But if we get the range start from 0 then we get the numbering of tag from 00 (myec2instance00).

Any other way to achieve the end result is also accepted as a valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to [range](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/range.html) is `start`. So you could do the following for example:

```
variable "nodes" {
  default = 5
}

locals {
  node_range = range(1, var.nodes + 1)
}


output "out" {
  value = local.node_range
}
```

which gives:

```
out = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
locals {
  node_range = range(1, var.nodes+1)
}
```